# Trouble on making example on primefaces autocomplete component

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I am learning how to use primefaces framework. I set up a project for making examples and I'm having some trouble with making an autocomplete component work. I wanted to show hints for "players" on this autocomplete component by it's name based on a source of players but no hints are shown. I don't have much experience on ajax neither on beans, obviously I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for helping!

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">>
    <h:head>
        <title>Autocomplete</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:autoComplete value="#{autoComplBean.selectedPlayer}" 
               completeMethod="#{autoComplete.complete}" var="p" 
               itemLabel="#{p.name}" itemValue="#{p}" dropdown="true">
            </p:autoComplete>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class autoComplBean {

    private acPlayer selectedPlayer;
    private ArrayList<acPlayer> autoCompleteList;

    public autoComplBean() {
        selectedPlayer = new acPlayer();
        autoCompleteList = new ArrayList();
        autoCompleteList.add(new acPlayer("rodri", "martinez", 22));
        autoCompleteList.add(new acPlayer("junior", "martinez", 27));
        autoCompleteList.add(new acPlayer("rodri", "heredia", 25));
        autoCompleteList.add(new acPlayer("juan", "gonzales", 22));
        autoCompleteList.add(new acPlayer("prueba", "jugador", 23));
        autoCompleteList.add(new acPlayer("otro", "player", 27));
        autoCompleteList.add(new acPlayer("auto", "complete", 101));
        autoCompleteList.add(new acPlayer("ajax", "primefaces", 29));
    }

    public ArrayList<acPlayer> complete(String query){
        ArrayList<acPlayer> players = readPlayers(query);
        return players;
    }

    public ArrayList<acPlayer> readPlayers(String name){

        if(name.equals("")){
            return autoCompleteList;
        }
        else{
            ArrayList<acPlayer> result = new ArrayList();
            for (acPlayer current : autoCompleteList) {
                if(current.getName().startsWith(name)){
                    result.add(current);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

    }

    public void setSelectedPlayer(acPlayer selectedPlayer) {
        this.selectedPlayer = selectedPlayer;
    }

    public void setAutoCompleteList(ArrayList<acPlayer> autoCompleteList) {
        this.autoCompleteList = autoCompleteList;
    }

    public acPlayer getSelectedPlayer() {
        return selectedPlayer;
    }

    public ArrayList<acPlayer> getAutoCompleteList() {
        return autoCompleteList;
    }

}

public class acPlayer {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;

    public acPlayer() {
        name = "";
        surname = "";
        age = 0;
    }

    public acPlayer(String name, String surname, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // setters getters
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get tooltip with additional information? There's an example for it: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteItemtip.jsf

While `itemValue` is the value set in bean, and `itemLabel` the text displayed in dropdown, for tooltip you need to use `facet name="itemtip"`:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{autoComplBean.selectedPlayer}" 
   completeMethod="#{autoComplete.complete}" var="p" 
   itemLabel="#{p.name}" itemValue="#{p}" dropdown="true">
   <f:facet name="itemtip">
    #{p.name} #{p.surname} (#{p.age})
   </f:facet>
</p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: I don' think an item tooltip is what he wants. he simply doesn't get any results when entering the name of a player.

Comment: @Rosty he writes he wants to have hints on players, for me as sounds like tooltips.